# Restrict jQuery append to only one element

Tags: jquery, append, load

I am using a combination of load() and append() to show more data on scroll on a website. 
However, it appends an infinite number of divs. Is there a way to either stop the execution after x number of appended items or to stop the function altogether after one action?

Ideally, I would like the function to append the `#test2` div once and then wait for the user to scroll down and append another div, let's say `#test3` below.

```js
$('.container').scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  if (($this.scrollTop() + $this.innerHeight() == $(this)[0].scrollHeight)) {
    $('#content-wrap').append($('<div>').load('data.html #test2'));
  }
});
```

**EDIT**
To include more information here's a more complete code of what I am trying to achieve:

There's a div on my website with a loaded #test1 and its corresponding .js file on a button click.

```
<div class="right">
 <div id="content-wrap">
 <!--- this is where the loaded content is displayed --->
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's the button's code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#menu-btn').click(function(){
    jQuery("#content-wrap").load("data.html #test1")
$.getScript("data.js");
    });
});
```

Now, when the user scrolls through that #test1 content, I would like to automatically show #test2 once the user hits the bottom of the page (see the first code).

The problem is that there's an infinite loop of #test1 divs that appear, instead of just one #test2 data. Then, once the user scrolls to the bottom of the page again, I would like to show #test3 data on so on until #testX.

What I am looking for is a way to append #test2 data only once and then append #test3, #test4 .... #testX on scroll.

Comment: Perhaps set a flag once the content is appended and add that flag to the `if` condition? Alternatively call `off()` to remove the scroll handler once the append happens. It's hard to understand the logic you want to create, as you say you don't want it to happen multiple times, then state that you want it to append `#test2` then `#test3`

Comment: I want to append a different div that contains different data. Right now it appends #test2 over and over again.

Comment: So what governs how you retrieve the different information?

Comment: That's why I asked the question. If I could stop the execution of this function I would probably create another function that uses the same code but change #test2 to #test3. I know that is not the most efficient way but the only solution I can see at this point.

Comment: There is 100% a more efficient way of doing that, but we need a much clearer description of what you want to achieve and how it's supposed to be affected by the elements you scroll through in the DOM

Comment: I have edited my question to include more information